# Using PowerShell Core ConvertFrom-Markdown to parse values in a markdown table

Tags: powershell, markdown

I'm interested in using the ConvertFrom-Markdown cmdlet to parse values in a markdown table.  The cmdlet uses the [markdig](https://github.com/xoofx/markdig) markdown processor, which has an [Abstract Syntax Tree](https://github.com/xoofx/markdig/blob/master/doc/parsing-ast.md) that should be able to be traversed for this purpose.

How can we search/enumerate the Tokens in the following powershell snippet to return the rows and columns?

```
(@'
# header1
## header2
| Column1 | Column2 |
| ------- | ------- |
| Row1Column1 | Row1Column2 |
| Row2Column1 | Ro2Column2 |
'@ | ConvertFrom-Markdown).Tokens
```

The values that I see in the Tokens look promising, I can see `Markdig.Extensions.Tables.TableCell` in the `Parent` fields, but that's about as far as I can get.

Comment: Using this [`ConvertFrom-SourceTable`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertFrom-SourceTable): `$YourMD | ConvertFrom-SourceTable`

Comment: Create variable for the markdown : $input = @' Your table '@.  Then (without tokens) : $table = $input | ConvertFrom-Markdown.   Now you have a Markdown Table.  Tokens were getting you only the tokens.  The cmdlet will return a c# class since PS is written in c#.  So you should be able to call any method in the c# class like $table.Parse(sourceText, pipeline).  You may need to cast PS object to their c# types like $table.Parse([string]sourceText, pipeline)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to do it.

Note I'm not sure if, example a `Table` can contain *only* `TableRow`s, so the `| where-object { ... }` might not be necessary.

```
# set up some sample data
$md = @"
# header1
## header2
| Column1 | Column2 |
| ------- | ------- |
| Row1Column1 | Row1Column2 |
| Row2Column1 | Ro2Column2 |
"@ | ConvertFrom-Markdown

# walk the syntax tree
$mdDoc = $md.Tokens;
$mdTables = @( $mdDoc | where-object { $_ -is [Markdig.Extensions.Tables.Table] } ); 
foreach( $mdTable in $mdTables )
{
    write-host "table";
    $mdRows = @( $mdTable | where-object { $_ -is [Markdig.Extensions.Tables.TableRow] } );
    foreach( $mdRow in $mdRows )
    {
        write-host "  row";
        write-host "    header = $($mdRow.IsHeader)";
        $mdCells = @( $mdRow | where-object { $_ -is [Markdig.Extensions.Tables.TableCell] } );
        foreach( $mdCell in $mdCells )
        {
            write-host "    cell";
            $mdInline = $mdCell.Inline;
            write-host "      inline - $($mdInline.Content)";
        }
    }
}
```

Which gives the following output:

```
table
  row
    header = True
    cell
      inline - Column1
    cell
      inline - Column2
  row
    header = False
    cell
      inline - Row1Column1
    cell
      inline - Row1Column2
  row
    header = False
    cell
      inline - Row2Column1
    cell
      inline - Ro2Column2
```

Hopefully that'll be enough to get you started...

Answer (score 0):

If you like to import the markdown tables into PowerShell arrays, you can parse and build PsCustomObjects as well along the way...

```
$MarkDown = @"
# header1
## header2
| Column1 | Column2 |
| ------- | ------- |
| Row1Column1 | Row1Column2 |
| Row2Column1 | Ro2Column2 |

| Table2 Column1 |
| ------------- |
| T2 Row1 |
| T2 Row2 |
| T2 Row3 |
"@ | ConvertFrom-Markdown

$mdDoc = $Markdown.Tokens
[array]$tables = $null
$mdTables = @($mdDoc | where {$_ -is [Markdig.Extensions.Tables.Table]})

foreach ($mdTable in $mdTables) {
    [array]$table = $null
    $mdRows = @($mdTable | where {$_ -is [Markdig.Extensions.Tables.TableRow]})

    foreach ($mdRow in $mdRows) {
        $mdCells = @($mdRow | where-object { $_ -is [Markdig.Extensions.Tables.TableCell]})
        $mdCellsValues = @($mdCells.Inline.Content | foreach {$_.ToString()})

        if ($mdRow.IsHeader) {# don't use headers as values
            $CustomProperties = $mdCellsValues
        } else {# iterate throw the customobject and populate it
            $thisrow = New-Object PSCustomObject | select $CustomProperties
            
            foreach ($i in 0..($CustomProperties.Count -1)) {
                $thisrow.($CustomProperties[$i]) = $mdCellsValues[$i]
            }

            $table += $thisrow
        }# endif

    }#end tablerows

    $tables += ,$table #add each table a sub arrays
    
}#end tables

$tables
```

The result is available in two sub arrays

```
C:\> $tables[0]

Column1     Column2
-------     -------
Row1Column1 Row1Column2
Row2Column1 Ro2Column2

C:\> $tables[1]

Table2 Column1
-------------
T2 Row1
T2 Row2
T2 Row3
```